# How to create a new nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

A  users can have many favorites top_songs,top_movies through songs and movies table.
A user registered user(current_user) want to post his favorites movies and songs.

Perhaps all Model association are right, i am stuck in controller and view (form).

When i submit from, i gets errors-

**Can't mass-assign protected attributes: songs**

How can i achieve this please?
all codes are below.

**User Model**

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
 attr_accessible :id, :name_special_char, :screenname, :fullname, :username, :prefix,   :firstname, :lastname,:middlename, :suffix, :age, :sex, :email,
:top_movies_attributes,:top_songs_attributes



  has_many :top_movies
  has_many :movies, through: :top_movies

  has_many :top_songs
  has_many :songs, through: :top_songs  

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :top_songs, :allow_destroy => true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :top_movies, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**Movie Model**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :top_movies
  has_many :users, through: :top_movies
end
```

**TopMovie Model**

```
class TopMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

**Song Model**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :top_songs
  has_many :users, through: :top_songs
end
```

**TopSong Model**

```
class TopSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :song
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

**Controller**

```
class MyTopFivesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @favorites = current_user
    @favorites=@favorites.movies.build()
    @favorites=@favorites.songs.build()

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @useraccounts_my_top_fife }
    end
  end

def create
    @favorites = current_user(params[:user])
    @favorites.save!
                        # Here i have stuck. i am not sure how to save.    
end
```

**view form**

```
  <%=nested_form_for  @favorites ,:url=>favorites_path(@favorites),:method=>'post' do |f| %>
      <label >Songs</label>   
            <%= f.fields_for :songs  do |songs| %>
             <div  id="Topsongs" >
                <div class="input-control text span5 place-left ">
                    <%= songs.text_field :name,:placeholder=>"songs name.." %>
                </div>
                <div class="span1 place-left">
                    <%= songs.link_to_remove "",  :class=>"icon-minus" %>
                </div>
            </div> 
        <% end %>       
        <span > 
            <%= f.link_to_add "", :songs, :class=>"icon-plus", :data => { :target => "#Topsongs" } %>
        </span>
        <label >movies</label>    
            <%= f.fields_for :movies  do |movies| %>
                <div id="Topmovies">
                    <div class="input-control text span5 place-left ">
                        <%= movies.text_field :name,:placeholder=>"movies name.." %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span1 place-left">
                        <%= movies.link_to_remove "",  :class=>"icon-minus" %>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            <% end %>       
        <span> 
            <%= f.link_to_add "", :movies, :class=>"icon-plus",:style=>"font-size: 14px;", :data => { :target => "#Topmovies" } %> 
        </span>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for setting up the associations here. One you have used by creating two join models for top songs and top movies. And other, to use polymorphic association.

Lets use polymorphic association. We are going to use User, Movie, Song and Favourite models for this stuff. The Favourite model will contain the polymorphic fields.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :id, :name_special_char, :screenname, :fullname, :username, :prefix, :firstname, :lastname,:middlename, :suffix, :age, :sex, :email       

  has_many :favourites
  has_many :movies, through: :favourites, source: :favouritable, source_type: 'Movie'
  has_many :songs, through: :favourites, source: :favouritable, source_type: 'Song'

end
```

**Movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :favourites, as: :favouritable
  has_many :users, through: :favourites
end
```

**Song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :favourites, as: :favouritable
  has_many :users, through: :favourites
end
```

**Favourite.rb**

```
class Favourite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :favouritable, polymorphic: true
end
```

We also need to create the migration for new model "Favourite". As of now, we just need 3 columns ie. `user_id, favouritable_id, favouritable_type`. Here favouritable_type and favouritable_id are the polymorphic fields. `favouritable_type` is a string and `favouritable_id` is reference type.

**Migration File**

```
class CreateFavourites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :favourites do |t|
     t.integer :user_id
     t.references :favouritable, polymorphic: true
     t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now, as we are going to mark some movies and songs to be favourite for a user, then we can place the code for building the data in UsersController instead of creating another controller or we can also create a controller for `Favourites`. I am going to use `UsersController` here. I am using update action to update the favourites as we don't need any extra functionality here. You can add a new action if you want.

**In UsersController.rb**

```
def edit_favourites #or some generic name
  @user = current_user.includes(:movies, :songs)
  @movies = Movie.all
  @songs = Song.all
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to users_path #user index page
  else
    if params[:user][:movie_ids].present? or params[:user][:song_ids].present?
      render :edit_favourites
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

**edit_favourites.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :movie_ids, "Favourite Movies: " %>
    <%= f.collection_select :movie_ids, @movies, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :song_ids, "Favourite Songs: " %>
    <%= f.collection_select :song_ids, @songs, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, Add the new action to routes.